Как выйти из скрипта groovy с ненулевым кодом выхода?
Всем доброго времени суток!
Пытаюсь выполнять скрипты groovy через jenkins-cli
$ echo "return 1" | ssh jenkins groovy = ; echo $?

Но код возврата всегда 0, если не было сгенерировано исключение. Возможно ли вообще выйти из скрипта groovy в нужном месте с нужным кодом возврата?
